# Currently applying for postdocs: had a demotivating discussion with my supervisor

Tags: postdocs, career-path

In my penultimate year of PhD I did not apply for postdocs. I decided to take this year as a gap year. I remember that before telling my supervisor, they were very encouraging, and told me I had very good chances at top research groups.

In my last year of PhD I did not do much. I barely finished one paper, and I was doing random non-research things that were not specific to my field.

I have started applying for postdocs (Astrophysics) since October, through job boards. I applied for several positions (>25). I still did not receive any response for an interview or rejection. I guess they are still filtering.

But what made me so sad these days is that my professor started to tell me to lower my hopes, and that I will not have much chances this year. Maybe, maybe I will get one at a place I am not super happy to work there. And that I should focus only on that. But in general, there is a non zero chance I would get zero postdoc offers. They were always encouraging, and especially last year it seemed a good chance. Now, it is like I do not have a future.

I just feel so bad. My intention was to do a postdoc for fun, just to have a nice experience before leaving academia for good (you can not do astrophysics outside academia, at least in my field).

I am also starting feeling very stupid, and not good enough for the job. I am thinking about all the possible errors I could have made in my research, that maybe I will not be able to do research, and why I wasted so much time instead of being more productive.

I am in my late-twenties, and I still have these sort of insecurities. I guess I still really care about the opinion of others and their views of me.

Comment: Sorry to hear things are not going well. But, I am not sure there is a question we can help with. Or?

Comment: ok make sense, I cancel. Sorry, just needed to write out.

Comment: Please don't sabotage your question. If you want a question to disappear, flag it and ask the mods to delete it.

Comment: Thank you, I thought it was not allowed. Thank you very much for your response @Buffy

Comment: Looking for a job in academia can be really hard psychologically, what you're experiencing is normal. Maybe it's obvious but just in case: if possible take care of your mental health, preferably with a professional.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From your description, it is possible that the professor is talking about the state of the academic market in you field at this moment and not about you or your potential for research.

You know better from their tone, of course, but don't rule this possibility out entirely.

And it shouldn't have any effect on what you do to obtain a position. You have to keep pushing. I also finished (long long ago) in a terrible market. I tried over a hundred places before I found even a temporary position. I was lucky to remain in academia at all, but never gave up.

Comment: Fully agree - Covid continues to impact, well, everything...

Comment: "I was lucky to remain in academia at all, but never gave up" - that's the spirit!